# Setting up a RecyclerView to FrameLayout issue in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-framelayout

I am trying to setup a RecyclerView which has the list items in a FrameLayout.

I have the following code:

```
// set up the RecyclerView
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new FrameLayoutManager(this));

recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The issue is that FrameLayoutManager is causing an error?!

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FrameLayoutManager` is not a `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`; i.e. it doesn't extend from it. so, they are different types.

As per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager) here are the valid RecyclerView LayoutManager classes:

- LinearLayoutManager
- StaggeredGridLayoutManager
- GridLayoutManager
- WearableLinearLayoutManager

Which extend from the abstract class `RecyclerView.LayoutManager`